# Warframe keeps playing when hitting escape, how do I pause?

Tags: warframe

I made a new account, and now every time I hit escape and bring up the menu, it doesn't pause the game. What happened? It's been about a month since I played; is this due to a new update?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Warframe, but it's an MMO. MMOs don't usually allow pausing...

Comment: Keep hating folks. I hadn't realised that playing solo allowed pausing, but otherwise you actually cannot pause. Y'know, as I stated in my answer, because no one actually pointed this out to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, dang. Turns out that if you put it on solo play you can pause with the esc menu. I'd had my previous account on solo; this one wasn't.

Comment: Solo / party play isn't an account setting, it's a lobby setting; when you're lining up a mission there should be a box where you can select whether you want to play solo, in a group friends can join, etc.
You don't need to create a new account in order to change this setting.

Comment: I have two accounts; I created the second one to start over with a friend. I did not understand why it would not pause while I was playing. No, it's not an account setting... but had you posted this before I figured it out, it would have been a bit more helpful. ;)